# Does malloc+strdup leak memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, strdup

With:

```
char *x = malloc(1024);
strcpy(x, "asdf");
x = strdup(x);
free(x); // OK
free(x); // Segfault
```

If I just free it once, will I still be leaking? And if so, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You leak memory because you forget the first pointer. Do it like this:

```
char * x = malloc(1024);
strcpy(x, "asdf");
char * y = strdup(x);

free(x); 
free(y);
```